# PNG: deflate and zlib

Tags: png, zlib, huffman-code, deflate

I'm trying to understand compression in PNG - but I seem to

find a lot of contradictory information online ...
I would like to understand 
- how is searching done in the LZ77-part: hash table with linked lists? is this defined in deflate? or implemented in zlib? is there a choice of the search method?
- can PNG encoders/decoders set some parameters for the compression (strategy, filter, etc.) or is there a default for PNG?
- does the LZ77-part do greedy or lazy evaluation? or is this an option too? 
- and finally: the 2 Huffman trees, are they compressed in a third tree, and all three of them are encoded? or are the 2 trees encoded with only their codelengths?

Is the zlib implementation different from other deflate implementations?? Perhaps that is where all my confusion comes from?

Thank you for any help!! I need this for my new job

LuCu

Comment: Some of your questions are answered in the official specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Compression.html

Comment: See also: http://www.zlib.net/feldspar.html

Comment: Yes there is a default for libpng (it uses the zlib default), but the settings for strategy and level can be reset via libpng functions such as png_set_compression_level(png_ptr, level).  The setting for filter also has a libpng default and can be set via png_set_filter().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PNG compression is in the  [zlib](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950) format.  The zlib format uses [deflate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).  The code used is commonly the [zlib library](http://zlib.net/).

The algorithm used for compression is not specified by the format.  The zlib library deflate algorithm uses hash chains to search for matching strings in a sliding window.  zlib's deflate takes several parameters for compression tuning -- see [`deflateInit2()`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h#L527).

The deflate format specifies the compression of the Huffman codes at the front of dynamic blocks.  The literal/length and distance code code lengths are run-length and Huffman coded themselves.

There are other implementations of deflate compressors in the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) and [Google's zopfli](https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/), where both of those use more intensive approaches that take more time for small gains in compression.